# Js: pass button id to the same page

Tags: javascript, php, jquery

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $(".Categories").click(function () {
            var catId = $(this).attr('id');
            catId = String(catId);

            jQuery.ajax({
                url: "index.php",
                data: { catId },
                type: "POST",
                success: function (data) {
                    $("#categoryField").html(data);
                }
            });
        });
    });
</script>
```

I need to pass my clicked button `id` to the same `index.php` page, without page refreshing and work with that `id` value.My code is wrong, because page is rendered second time.

Here is my php code:

```
<?php
$category=$user_home->runQuery("SELECT DISTINCT category FROM products");
$category->execute();

$categoryArray=$category->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);

  foreach($categoryArray as $listID){
?>

<input type="button" id="<?php echo $listID['category']?>" class="Categories" value="<?php echo $listID["category"]?>"/><br>
<?

}
?>
```

Comment: Can you share executable demo/snippet or [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/) ?

Comment: Any error in console ? Is page getting reloaded ?

Answer (score 0):

Call `preventDefault` method inside the button `click` event handler to prevent default button behaviour ("*page is rendered second time*"):

```
...
$(".Categories").click(function (e) {
    e.preventDefault();
...
```

Answer (score 0):

There is a syntax error in your code

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $(".Categories").click(function () {
        var catId = $(this).attr('id');
        catId = String(catId);

        jQuery.ajax({
            url: "index.php",
            data: { catId: catId },
            type: "POST",
            success: function (data) {
                $("#categoryField").html(data);
            }
        });
    });
});
```

You have to pass data in valid literal object format. {"property_name": "property_value"}.

Change: **data: { catId }** to data: **{ "catId": catId }**

For server side:

```
<?

if (isset($_POST['catId'])) {

    /* YOUR CODE FOR CATEGORY */

    $catId = intval($_POST['catId']);

    echo 'SUCCESS';

    exit(0);
}

// YOU OTHER PHP CODE 
?>
```

Comment: But i still have my main problem, after i post that variable, am getting all page content second time in `"#categoryField"` id. Maybe i need to pass variable without `success:`  section if it is possible

Comment: We need more samples and information to understand you problem

Comment: If you want to send data only to the same page, you have to make some changes in your PHP file too. First of all you have to catch ajax query to your page. Example: if ($_POST['catId']) { /* YOUR CODE */ ; echo 'SUCCESS'; exit(0) }. Something like this...

Comment: am doing this 
`if (isset($_POST["catId"])){

$catId=$_POST["catId"];

echo $catId;`

Comment: And what about exit(0) in case of ajax request? See my php sample in my updated answer

Comment: if (isset($_POST["catId"])){ $catId=$_POST["catId"]; echo $catId; exit(0)

Thanks, now it works fine, but after button is pressed some of my tables  with data changing their locations on the screen.That is strange because i do nothing with them in  this code

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/108078/discussion-between-ali-mamedov-and-darius92).

Answer (score 0):

I think I need to post my variable to another page and then return it.I dont know how to do it in same page.This variant with `exit(0)` is bad because all variables inside `if` statement after `exit(0)` will be deleted.

```
<?

if (isset($_POST['catId'])) {

    /* YOUR CODE FOR CATEGORY */

    $catId = intval($_POST['catId']);

    echo 'SUCCESS';

    exit(0);
}

// YOU OTHER PHP CODE 
?>
```